# Deploying Django project on Centos 8, using Gunicorn, Nginx (Gunicorn.service problem)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, centos8

I followed this tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7

1. Tried to deploy Django project on ***centos 8***
2. Everything went fine and worked, except ***gunicorn.service***

```
    [Unit]
    Description=gunicorn daemon
    After=network.target
        
    [Service]
    User=facealatoo
    Group=nginx
    WorkingDirectory=/home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed
    ExecStart=/home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed/venv/bin/gunicorn \ 
        --workers 3 \
        --bind unix:/home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed/promed.sock \
        configs.wsgi:application

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

1. #### Folders destinations
2. my project folder destination ***'/home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed'*** settings.py file ***'home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed/configs/settings.py'***
3. server user name ***'facealatoo'***
4. ***after running***

```
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    sudo systemctl start gunicorn
    sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
    sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
```

## Error message

```
    ● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor 
    preset: disabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-05-15 18:37:22 +06; 13s 
    ago
    Main PID: 32293 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        
    May 15 18:37:22 facealatoo.net.kg systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
    May 15 18:37:22 facealatoo.net.kg systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main 
    process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
    May 15 18:37:22 facealatoo.net.kg systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed 
    with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please help me! ;) Thanks in advance ))))

Comment: Did you checked this part `configs.wsgi:application`? is your `wsgi` under "/home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed/config"?

How do you run your app in standalone mode i.e just running your app with gunicorn, can you share the working cli?

Comment: yes my wsgi file exactly in  /home/facealatoo/nadyr/promed/configs directory
I have already fixed this problem by changing socket file destination to the 'facealatoo/'. Anyway thanks a lot for responding ))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just change socket file destination (home/facealatoo(user)/) and gunicorn destination (usr/local/bin/gunicorn). And these actions solved my problem)))